# List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject when scheduling the class

Tags: apex

```
public static List<Account> AccountsRequiringDebtCase()
    {   
         Integer creditTermDate30 = 2;
         Integer creditTermDate35 = 7;
         Integer creditTermDate45 = 17;
        List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
        if(Date.today().Day()==creditTermDate30){
            accList.add([
                select Id, Has_Open_Debt_Case__c, Most_Recent_Statement_Date__c 
                from Account where
                Has_Open_Debt_Case__c = FALSE and
                Day_60_Balance__c > 0 and Credit_Terms__c = 30 

            ]);  
        }
```

if i put limit to 1 its working, but i want to get the list of records with the matching criteria.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to go through [how to ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and then [edit your question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/264634/edit) to provide the exact details where you are getting the error. If you can provide the entire stack trace, then that would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you, still i am getting error as "Cannot modify a collection while its being iterated", when i tried to add accList.addAll([ select Id, Has_Open_Debt_Case__c, Most_Recent_Statement_Date__c from Account where Has_Open_Debt_Case__c = FALSE and Day_60_Balance__c > 0 and Credit_Terms__c = 30 ]); Please help me on this Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The Apex [`List`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm) class's `add()` method takes one sObject. When you pass a SOQL query as the argument of this method, it forces the system to evaluate the query in a single-sObject context:

```
        accList.add([
            select Id, Has_Open_Debt_Case__c, Most_Recent_Statement_Date__c 
            from Account where
            Has_Open_Debt_Case__c = FALSE and
            Day_60_Balance__c > 0 and Credit_Terms__c = 30 

        ]);
```

This requires that the query return exactly one object, yielding an exception if the list is either empty or contains more than one record.

To avoid evaluating the query in a single-sObject context, use `List.addAll()`, whose parameter is a `List<Object>`, instead.